# Rigid motion in Euclidean geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I've always thought (until this day) that "rigid motion" and "isometry" were synonimous in Euclidean geometry. Yesterday I read again the (informal) definition of "rigid motion":

"A rigid motion of a subspace $S$ of Euclidean space is a motion of $S$ that preserves the shape of $S$."

According to this definition a reflection in plane geometry is not a rigid motion (but nonentheless it is an isometry). I'm aware that this problem can be solved by restricting ourselves to "proper isometries" (i.e. isometries with determinant=1). Nevertheless I didn't find this definition satisfying so I tried to come up with my own rigorous definition of "rigid motion".

In my opinion, the most intuitive option is the following:

"A rigid motion in an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $E$ is an isometry $\mathcal{I}:E\to E$ that is homotopic to the identity $\mathsf{id}_E$ (and the intermediate maps of this homotopy are also isometries)."

My idea was that moving a subspace $S$ through the Euclidean space is just like a continous family of isometric embeddings that starts with the inclusion of $S$ into $E$. Since we are working with finite dimensional real spaces isometries from a metric subspace can always be extended to an isometry of the whole space (the extension may not be unique, but I don't think the choice really matters).

Does my definition characterize "proper isometries" (in the context of finite dimensional real spaces) ?

Clearly a map satisfying my definition is a proper isometry because the determinant is a continous map.

Comment: The key is that the group $O(n)$ has exactly two connected components, one of which is $SO(n)$.

Comment: This is fascinating. I didn't thought that I could see the homotopies that I described as paths in the Lie group $O(n)$.

Comment: I will add a proper answer once I am back to my computer.